# Galaxy Tab - How to keep alerts visible until the screen is unlocked?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, alerts

I've noticed that when I get an alert (an incoming email, or a notification from an app (**cough** *Words with Friends* **cough**) and the screen is locked, I'll hear the alert sound but, when I wake up the tablet, I won't see the alert.

Is there any way of having the tablet leave those alerts on the screen until I wake it up?

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab 7.0 wifi-only, running Honeycomb 3.2.

Comment: So... nothing? Not even that this isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Samsung flavor of Android (and possibly others?) keeps the alerts accesible, but very well-hidden. Click on the section of the bottom menu bar with the time, then slide up where it reads "Settings". The alerts are visible there.